# Where can I see modifications made to the PATH environment variable by the Go installer

Tags: macos, mojave, bash, environment-variables

I've identified several changes to the PATH variable in Bash that aren't listed in e.g. `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`.

The following snippet from the Go installation page mentions that packages may change the environment.

How can I see changes to the environment made by packages?

https://golang.org/doc/install

> The package should put the /usr/local/go/bin directory in your PATH
>   environment variable. You may need to restart any open Terminal
>   sessions for the change to take effect.

Comment: There are various places where such changes can occur. As you seem to focus on Go installation right now, I've changed the question title accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/etc/profile` file, which Bash executes for login shells, includes the following content:

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

It's the `path_helper` program that sets up the `PATH` environment variable.

`man path_helper`:

> The `path_helper` utility reads the contents of the files in the
>   directories `/etc/paths.d` and `/etc/manpaths.d` and appends their
>   contents to the `PATH` and `MANPATH` environment variables respectively. 
>   ...

In particular, the Go installer creates a file called `go` in `/etc/paths.d` with the following content:

```
cat /etc/paths.d/go 
/usr/local/go/bin
```